# Add comment to excel using python win32

Tags: python, excel, comments, xlsx, win32com

I am trying to add new comment to excel with python, using win32.

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\...\.xlsx')
ws = wb.Worksheets('sheet1')
ws.Cells(1,1).AddComment = "comment"
```

--> object has no attribute 'AddComment'

Do you know how to add new comment to excel using win32? 
Thank you!

Comment: What's the reason, that you are using win32 over openpyxl or xlsxwriter ?

Comment: Because I should save exciting xlsx file format (charts, images..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add comment is a method not a property.

```
ws = wb.Worksheets('sheet1')
ws.Cells(1,1).AddComment("comment")
```

Just read the the [documentation in the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-addcomment-method-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Thank you very much for answer and documentation!

Comment: As you are new to stackoverflow. Mark it also as an answer if it solves the problem!

Comment: Do you know how delete exciting comment? I tryed ws.Cells(1,1).ClearComments, but it don't work.

Comment: ws.Cells(1,1).Comment.Delete() - works! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/comment-delete-method-excel

Comment: Use a new question for such cases. Stackoverflow is not a discussion platform.