# Open an Excel file, change background colors and add comments, and save it (python)

Tags: python, excel

There are several packages in Python for reading and writing Excel files. Some of these packages understand formatting, some do not.

I want to read an existing Excel file and change the background color of some of the cells. I want to add comments to these cells explaining why their color was changed. Then I want to save them out again.

Is there any way to do this? I am looking for a pure python solution, not one that runs excel, as I need to do this in batch.

Comment: inb4 "what have you tried so far?" if all else fails: win32com (pypiwin32) should let you add comments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47222373/add-comment-to-excel-using-python-win32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is be fairly easy with openpyxl (https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/comments.html) but keep in mind that the original comments (if any are present) will be overwritten.

Here is a simple fragment that sets the background color and adds a comment:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.comments import Comment
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border

wb = load_workbook(fname)
ws = wb.active
redFill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFF0000', end_color='FFFF0000', fill_type='solid')

ws['A1'].comment = Comment("Comment for A1","No Such Author")
ws['A2'].fill = redFill
wb.save(fname)
```

Comment: It is fairly easy. I'll edit your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use pypiwin32 as below

```
import win32.client as win32
app = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = app.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Range("A1").Interior.Color = 255
ws.Range("A1").AddComment("Comment Text Here")
app.Quit()
```

Comment: That works, but I would like a pure python solution, as I need to do this without starting up excel.

Comment: openpyxl is your best bet then, though I'm not sure of the exact code: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#