# Add comment to Excel cell with Python 2.7

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

I'm using Python 2.7 and I try to do what's [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comments.html) (adding comments to a excel file worksheet with Python) and this doesn't work...

Here's my code :

```
import os, sys, shutil, time, openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.comments import Comment
...
path = 'K:/....../data.xlsx'
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
...
comment = ws["A1"].comment
comment = Comment('This is the comment text', 'Comment Author')
...
wb.save(path)
```

I also tried :

```
comment = Comment('This is the comment text', 'Comment Author')
ws["A1"].comment = comment
```

but whether this creates me my xlsx file without comment on the "A1" cell, whether this is telling me "TypeError : expected type 'unicode' " and "raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))".

Could you please help me fix this ? Thank you

N.B. : I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47222373/add-comment-to-excel-using-python-win32) but it says "no attribute AddComment"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going by the error message, it sounds like `Comment` is expecting its arguments to be Unicode, but you're giving it 8-bit strings. Try giving it Unicode strings instead.

```
comment = Comment(u'This is the comment text', u'Comment Author')
```

If you're thinking "but why do I need to prefix my literals with `u` when they don't do that in the examples in the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/comments.html)?", then most likely those examples are using Python 3, where unprefixed string literals are interpreted to be Unicode.

---

As for the question of "which of these is correct?":

```
comment = ws["A1"].comment
comment = Comment(u'This is the comment text', u'Comment Author')
```

or

```
comment = Comment(u'This is the comment text', u'Comment Author')
ws["A1"].comment = comment
```

The second one makes more sense to me. Assigning a value to the variable `comment`, and then assigning a second value to it, is fairly nonsensical; it won't cause the two values to become related in any interesting way. The second one is much more likely to actually make a change to your worksheet.

Comment: Thank you very much, that exactly fixed my issue ! And thank you a lot for explaining me the reason behind. I have a huge lack of knowledge in terms of what are the differences between Python 2 and 3 (on the way of coding) and I'm urged to use Python 2 (no Python 3 allowed) so it's hard sometimes when I find solution for a problem that doesn't work because it's thought to be running on 3 ! Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#full script on xlsxwriter

import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart_styles.xlsx')

# Show the styles for all of these chart types.
chart_types = ['column', 'area', 'line', 'pie']

for chart_type in chart_types:

    # Add a worksheet for each chart type.
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(chart_type.title())
    worksheet.set_zoom(30)
    style_number = 1

    # Create 48 charts, each with a different style.
    for row_num in range(0, 90, 15):
        for col_num in range(0, 64, 8):

            chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': chart_type})
            chart.add_series({'values': '=Data!$A$1:$A$6'})
            chart.set_title ({'name': 'Style %d' % style_number})
            chart.set_legend({'none': True})
            chart.set_style(style_number)

            worksheet.insert_chart(row_num, col_num , chart)
            style_number += 1

# Create a worksheet with data for the charts.
data_worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Data')
data = [10, 40, 50, 20, 10, 50]
data_worksheet.write_column('A1', data)
data_worksheet.hide()

workbook.close()
```

Comment: hope this help , its complete script on xlsxwriter